# Access part of the list in c#

Tags: c#

I have this two list here:

```
List<KeyValuePair<TextBox, KeyValuePair<string, Type>>> textbox1
```

So, i need that to get the Textbox i need to write:

```
textbox1.Key
```

What should i type to get the `KeyValuePair<string, Type>>` Type, like textbox1.Value.Value?
The type contains string or int.What i need is to access it's value so i can assign an if operator but i don't know how to. Then i need to modify it but that's my next step and i can arrange that myself.

Comment: Please paste some sample. I completetly cannot understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Why do you need a list of key value pairs of key value pairs in the first place? Perhaps it would be a better idea to make use of the `TextBox.Tag` property?

Comment: It's complicated, that's what we could arrange. So what i need is to access the textbox and at the same time the type

Comment: @MAL - Please take some time to construct your questions, judging from your recent questions you are at risk of an automatic ban from the system for low quality questions... Having saying that, why not just set a breakpoint, and look at the value to see what you would need to type to access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose `textbox1.Key` won´t compile since `textbox1` is a List and therefor does not have any member called `Key`. Having said this the following may work for you:

```
textbox[i].Value.Value
```

Where `i` is the index of your KV-pair within the list (rather then the actual key)